# Why won't this Regex match in C# console, but yet matches in http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Tags: c#, regex

Given this code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = @"<RETS ReplyCode='0' ReplyText='V2.7.0 2235: Success'>
<COUNT Records='35' />
<DELIMITER value = '09'/>
<COLUMNS>   PropObjectKey   PropMediaKey    PropMediaType   PropMediaExternalKey    PropItemNumber  PropMediaDisplayOrder   PropMediaSize   PropMimeType    PropMediaBytes  PropMediaFileName   PropMediaCaption    PropMediaDescription    PropMediaURL    PropMediaCreatedTimestamp   PropMediaModificationTimestamp  County  PropMediaSystemLocale   PropMediaSubSystemLocale    UniqueID    ListingID   PropertyType    PropMediaPixelLength    PropMediaPixelWidth </COLUMNS>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632498 50000967225     31  31  50045650613 10000000378 77466   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/YismiRDzpzRAA785VjAgK9B6HZ39R15Uf8FHs6zNrYQLHH5oXNifWCpWucd464mB_QOLrocd0Mzi3tcxXF7-OtXuYL_Nn4cPOxbMfi2_NSJfjOLvl3rziSfNYeRIY0pq.jpg  2013-07-26 18:35:58 2013-08-12 10:47:11 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/YismiRDzpzRAA785VjAgK9B6HZ39R15Uf8FHs6zNrYQLHH5oXNifWCpWucd464mB_QOLrocd0Mzi3tcxXF7-OtXuYL_Nn4cPOxbMfi2_NSJfjOLvl3rziSfNYeRIY0pq.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/eHNqsRrgGczYWPkih-Knsvh5oQhfTnlATrtfleEslXaaUz6X77EtmX6d_CuOaJkDpNc6m6FUWhovo_MyVmGAeO4d12sdzD6lw51YvikILOG-N5sctkxfeag0ikUPA9yW.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/1duvzD5XKHTX-dh7Mc9FfzXXXQPO07oT1xAnoTJ98x78vCtR-XjPVk7mEYOV6CV-8v1a94Zi0qXKWMWGuhn-BUjO3bfZyHOpCfRyG0jJfxp6C5TVd2v4MngSXKeEn41j.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632499 50000967225     32  32  50045650613 10000000378 74181   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/dJTC-PgIJpqbcCJQppIoNL5_tkk3xiszta952j7Z8QYb34O_aCe_LnVa2DcQW7_cKn7AYW526Olc5NTuDxwetHllzN4KTHKELRUVNIXWtjMViiS0aBk_9Mq0ivcBCIbt.jpg  2013-07-26 18:35:59 2013-08-12 10:47:12 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/dJTC-PgIJpqbcCJQppIoNL5_tkk3xiszta952j7Z8QYb34O_aCe_LnVa2DcQW7_cKn7AYW526Olc5NTuDxwetHllzN4KTHKELRUVNIXWtjMViiS0aBk_9Mq0ivcBCIbt.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/2FHcUza48Cok9hOQh4cDf5-3ejZJBtsI3E-7b8MYYSJacdC1ZTsfoxWqCrLrdAuPgeW5hqzCX0fhFevrgP8iVA-FFX6ugKFOmWn92ivXRPlN5CFL4RsQuq3tExZ66SCX.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/HxJn_eAsGTBSslmq4yeCrkxfur5P6WUgY1wMslhSeT3wiNdFmbIuMIdzgZ2YxfkEIHajwuQpQ-BK8x9hs6D2hGKl2d0djiCA3241qR9WRxxhCLuyCiXZMaqnr-zaYm26.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632500 50000967225     33  33  50045650613 10000000378 82152   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/57XHkhi-9OI3Prb8IjUKporjnjtd4Vm2hSFWggPCcetF6qgeIg7713MLWUVKxvu8yXnpEWInp9uJtAXNb5RvlxUP0FF6l9izd8PR8eij_gm6Ue98-pF_9mFKmk78zZay.jpg  2013-07-26 18:35:59 2013-08-12 10:47:12 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/57XHkhi-9OI3Prb8IjUKporjnjtd4Vm2hSFWggPCcetF6qgeIg7713MLWUVKxvu8yXnpEWInp9uJtAXNb5RvlxUP0FF6l9izd8PR8eij_gm6Ue98-pF_9mFKmk78zZay.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/Z3dgCkx0Tok_Kn43LWZrvBuH5ofQkZjP2UNEqWonrJT0HkcrJ28wDJrIHSxbVDcJEmBFS8UDghzR9CL-u49RrPs3IhtFzNxmsncN2RyH4Utxd2_nfL9UfIlXaOUfEkU4.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/-u2uba04qiPgGUpNH5C1TRuHKgQ4PHzI07S8CxgqA8A7wOjoW_0liVzAFylMBC-f7mrb7duxuZJRhozbgCKqJAAR-bYHxca0fBXzgIyFubZGUcSx9RxavNU6el89hfaC.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632501 50000967225     34  34  50045650613 10000000378 68352   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/gy_sjVAWCLKWSNDPfWWjZeYY8Cxekk11J-xRx1uB5LlEZ3xH9us6Kllcvx82uYfGiDbQu7QA-4MXUY5j2aJiMWAJmDrK8fqJ4yefsTBr54vWEXIx1hwx2QhLW5qYAU3B.jpg  2013-07-26 18:35:59 2013-08-12 10:47:13 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/gy_sjVAWCLKWSNDPfWWjZeYY8Cxekk11J-xRx1uB5LlEZ3xH9us6Kllcvx82uYfGiDbQu7QA-4MXUY5j2aJiMWAJmDrK8fqJ4yefsTBr54vWEXIx1hwx2QhLW5qYAU3B.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/YQcJLrmCJMMadVdlXNVPLr72N-5ohIN23TnP4_1j6XOSyetswVKmlZDqsSVPcUwFO_Z_k9ix4Evm21JZLH5EHYNCAJI8diHGqSUV9QIEVElZai2JxIpmcwJkyTIeXtfb.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/xw1tCP1jaXNDym2Bcxg_msiD6qwlTvIfy-8Q6iMMF97klnm1LNU0Le3XHtyalWBuTEtWQiM2egOErV7a2Ni98tDnDF-XGZeJzMgBEMW5tLj0rvDf0GoNDJgUXBkNd6WJ.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632502 50000967225     35  35  50045650613 10000000378 54611   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/53g6BsCAYOOu_LKZrxMUMsMfCrQJeeKlSrSb6e3hxavyfunD6bX9Lcm2gXogRj9ZLkPb0Vq4nwvG9MPfTaFARUMO6gNvcX3GgtaJLvqM-OwJFNpeRTWbyxLlL1Ocuiiz.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:00 2013-08-12 10:47:14 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/53g6BsCAYOOu_LKZrxMUMsMfCrQJeeKlSrSb6e3hxavyfunD6bX9Lcm2gXogRj9ZLkPb0Vq4nwvG9MPfTaFARUMO6gNvcX3GgtaJLvqM-OwJFNpeRTWbyxLlL1Ocuiiz.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/d3HvwaN9qSFb8wwsopWUHkqj57WijxYYxU-vMwxdUiQKcSnGBOR-E_YVzELnwNOIRLmt75RarVslF9b2_2oTri5HCBUMi01S3BM3Gcu6CWlyR6PjJntdaLPXZUe-HrQC.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/yDipTlnOdshMrOdjWPHpi3X1H_eA83meEsr9XRsz6P-rJhxg9V3zF4Mm6RAs0oEV7lBWUuvYsUZX5OPw7VnSVAHWkPQQGAiV86h6U2h7o7PJlWn-qwQX6RAfcnuruC7C.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632508 50000967225     10  10  50045650613 10000000378 41504   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/dgenRv2sonVQVp51IU0_qF29eohgQTaSeUHKCcKHZGazHL5Fe9FhOnlSzUGxm_FfTW6u3-s92FdlJzz3KimMSRuUMdSjsjM7-yPYihg2-lwxVWFdrG-0nrhv2yBhGK41.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:01 2013-08-12 10:47:15 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/dgenRv2sonVQVp51IU0_qF29eohgQTaSeUHKCcKHZGazHL5Fe9FhOnlSzUGxm_FfTW6u3-s92FdlJzz3KimMSRuUMdSjsjM7-yPYihg2-lwxVWFdrG-0nrhv2yBhGK41.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/skjJSZ-efBdi_igVWGEZ-S4ls_fsJTJMzDiW8jGGT6tz4XilVGDwOlbZydFRssUFeBRlr30GGJicrFMiHb4vrMkx-mIBPDNB3apH_bErFr0ogEv4Xq9Hew5DMiL2QTJA.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/gg8M_nfiaGEIQ85NBWkN_B3r2pt5HW4kSM7uX8z_KseHse0F29GQXMVyKliLhcdFH83Ra_ZyF19JXTaQgmsFw9Dn_ZBwdFdZRo7wtJTGmv64Woy2F6CO6TxuG3bfabum.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632509 50000967225     11  11  50045650613 10000000378 39169   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/F1v7D6RoUuIt7nvHVsOXlfeD8anyp_KS82o1XnQV3oAoBtf3QPujkBD5c2YGuXhEXxcMxQTwZK6OAxGSCdOILt12iDF39TEAV46KuCzMGFoeAIp0rSjczG1dSzkqfhIR.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:01 2013-08-12 10:47:15 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/F1v7D6RoUuIt7nvHVsOXlfeD8anyp_KS82o1XnQV3oAoBtf3QPujkBD5c2YGuXhEXxcMxQTwZK6OAxGSCdOILt12iDF39TEAV46KuCzMGFoeAIp0rSjczG1dSzkqfhIR.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/oUwxhFbm_aQ9LyYoE4oO3yy9DnmyRze1x2ciWvoXZ6nYrgQqgIk7Bp8oqQhT5vy22laU53yttsFHdplLRJbWkkVNCWzlALVSfrQi1mbLR1ug-AXHEdLlZg4BeQkrLdva.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/rr7X2RsmiYqVGICH3kiT9aW51rGbuyKYkQufrawihpwZSF-Tu9reBbBPB2mhZY4iVL5tLgPxjqi3G6A2QSA4aO4vjWYL_ymDQI8LRj-bHx_rYhuBDbTNJJZfF1B5scSb.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632510 50000967225     12  12  50045650613 10000000378 36537   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/7D5jytF8aCDsIBJHdCSENE4wkhhS-OpfV9SJwUs3LZdClNoCv3nLiBSn6az7ziz_sIw1q1-03-EZEs68qD3WfUwIHV_Alvd0AWhuBZICAd9bSuc-Ij82JV3nZ2bjCCiF.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:02 2013-08-12 10:47:16 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/7D5jytF8aCDsIBJHdCSENE4wkhhS-OpfV9SJwUs3LZdClNoCv3nLiBSn6az7ziz_sIw1q1-03-EZEs68qD3WfUwIHV_Alvd0AWhuBZICAd9bSuc-Ij82JV3nZ2bjCCiF.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/np7Zn9mhXTFrOKsCVxHakfmLBfvDJOpx0eXjEEmNS87Lf66rF3lQ4dPWMFjkEdpWZpub7Y7oTBXgiG-aIVKml8UR6MFQimB28TDrda93FYqW0XV-nEIyDyzgJACFazli.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/GjDCuFHwDgO0hhd28ZdFdTvdGCSoVMvaSNlsFi1tMf3ucVpeHr-0uxteJE956I8Kz2SQ4Pmnwo4XJBEUs9YiSPrMfCWJIrqHt9tyLdA08TnKgYlgiHWtlOmZB1ox6SBZ.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632511 50000967225     13  13  50045650613 10000000378 27721   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/OuJYNz2FNBKANF-TFDheIO7EwrMqCF7p_4-yFAguL4TZ_pd2krPGw7mROMjibyfqImnHtmytBmMijlOYYOwd5HbMj6L40VLnshcLIaGxfZiMWJPq7t_CypEc2F43om_M.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:02 2013-08-12 10:47:16 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/OuJYNz2FNBKANF-TFDheIO7EwrMqCF7p_4-yFAguL4TZ_pd2krPGw7mROMjibyfqImnHtmytBmMijlOYYOwd5HbMj6L40VLnshcLIaGxfZiMWJPq7t_CypEc2F43om_M.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/taTqbTddP63q7w0Ab-A-3qZwaHWF0BYrwlfacluTI7t5kMtzOp8lKdsba7Dh_01iUcng39JjUvVSbYaaMMHye4k_1S48AoJLxvmc_4j20ogtNc2YKbHEfXqSZ5PYtEsf.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/W7hOajWeKTVkz2vQvXOL-iWttTHgxXu1vyIJSffXf3mauAfZ0EuVgmcfaeXBP9KmhsQCBjHfTigwb4jraYOSHpFGLUfOBagYWQiCYJcSs32oVCrLcTXVNxmyFHWHOGRH.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632512 50000967225     26  26  50045650613 10000000378 68994   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/p7LXqiiz7NprS94TKM7oqYby5uSa40iRTet24w23pbg8uqJA462fxUHRxMPmPiSEIswPuXOATqmxobacK_dDaaJUhI-quuAA9aUFmSSn7QrWt_21IBqwKXTw3gQBx-oU.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:02 2013-08-12 10:47:16 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/p7LXqiiz7NprS94TKM7oqYby5uSa40iRTet24w23pbg8uqJA462fxUHRxMPmPiSEIswPuXOATqmxobacK_dDaaJUhI-quuAA9aUFmSSn7QrWt_21IBqwKXTw3gQBx-oU.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/-Me9YgSO7O--nz7pQGWd68TRSRUcBg6o8nXMt4icD0r4cKuKRidRoN4tvxDIUgY1a3ZQOsafYiZB-AIpXWx-k2GhaCLHlt6UfzS9GuwcMzCwil_hyMRrkBSh7y-Lfy__.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/854KANg4hpKN8HXRO4kAJXiLqVdcR_FoRcWF9x3y8aXLZ9CtO7LWL7dK7OGZJF0yyjek9rld8w4dvGNC7UxvZuE08WltBIk8dRarxILI2ntZMzWHhLBko39KTWbeSahF.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632513 50000967225     27  27  50045650613 10000000378 74014   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/zpl5BY93UeHhaRXB9lmg-4ySxWMM0F2TbdKbIYpQeTSmy1wNQZNcfRLgqnEpcGDFgx4hi5AK6FPrUVHh_cSTFHZj7Bm8dTb_w_8a-48Iw3BE7OinfMzZnE6m1eJ6OoPI.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:02 2013-08-12 10:47:17 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/zpl5BY93UeHhaRXB9lmg-4ySxWMM0F2TbdKbIYpQeTSmy1wNQZNcfRLgqnEpcGDFgx4hi5AK6FPrUVHh_cSTFHZj7Bm8dTb_w_8a-48Iw3BE7OinfMzZnE6m1eJ6OoPI.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/pieM-Nf1N_GSCcmd9uWJLra1fyXZuaRbJbx5U2KXWg7D_WhGny_bWAMxwUjhPom6DO5KpQ_co1NIAm_cPKORqA_d_vgYEviDw13RK54RMEo2C-62Yo4fSBbsezrWVngt.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/oc5S49-ssH0KCsoUyw0SgG1wEHeoosNjK0CTv-VL-fPp9NmUokTuI7VIEv_sF7bnbVyV-GbKRfDPx5Pu8VntKx-5awgU4AXJYSQ56cRNeZHVEodmOkdq-8tQbOtc79yc.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632514 50000967225     28  28  50045650613 10000000378 56540   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/H9npHDi9rTFaHD42CksMlYbPAOm3BbgUhLKmTr9KzTyDqEQcQ3UAO4NBMAUoh-mIaJ9_u_HaqlICskYflVE2beGmvTUJPEIjmNiOoMMiIKpjwXd46KnaMFS-YVKGrnVr.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:03 2013-08-12 10:47:10 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/H9npHDi9rTFaHD42CksMlYbPAOm3BbgUhLKmTr9KzTyDqEQcQ3UAO4NBMAUoh-mIaJ9_u_HaqlICskYflVE2beGmvTUJPEIjmNiOoMMiIKpjwXd46KnaMFS-YVKGrnVr.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/bfLMQ3zb4jmDmUeiC-JszDCGoqr_G912XTrOPhRf9SHssSQZrmMVXtHItOgexxZPhL8ZbR3rTpQv3IeEbO6PaUhlSI2eli0qvslPnQYf6DdepgQqiymuwEvlyRLAP57i.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/jF2gst1zId73D1BhWYBZtmJhp3HGaHxO1Ar1Lhq3TfmBiUfORFuLor1hK_NhydnLdkZ_MUZZGybDvk1HopkkqGpJFUvpBMyCixWMbKe3JivvQ40mNysZkvmE9TWBDN2q.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632515 50000967225     29  29  50045650613 10000000378 76557   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/PpvW4BgLFfiu6MkSCypeJvbVXUMPFNCZ5VtTi4ZiHEXxQlkfosMQ4LirpNrL5ndiz24PVKMe7d3VhaK-QMEp3jUcP_pEj-HuNlKIQchyVk7KBtJRs7FXWQRKjiPtO4l8.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:03 2013-08-12 10:47:10 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/PpvW4BgLFfiu6MkSCypeJvbVXUMPFNCZ5VtTi4ZiHEXxQlkfosMQ4LirpNrL5ndiz24PVKMe7d3VhaK-QMEp3jUcP_pEj-HuNlKIQchyVk7KBtJRs7FXWQRKjiPtO4l8.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/njbR-P1MLEM8DT-lAOFV7boGk2uxAIbR7uO5u9ZFa25pRRxX9bBlUSL4gRTU_WB3mwpnwUXzLHFRn0PuNay2PChIk_4L9jCL0Tmvqm1jliK_jWGAvBh-c2GG2q47DIEQ.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/uT-0ekCAgkh47e3V3kKP3hoyeGJiahAECJyPa6fzXf11prKGtpxtTFBM53g3XAqyHwtWoxh7f_Uv8H3JdUXmK0I9wQ35QZ_gIIR3L_55YPNkIHOAvL8PfxWo14Pi8YPH.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632516 50000967225     30  30  50045650613 10000000378 43106   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/_zGVT5UxrXQveqA78HL1Cqaz6YJ6EaBE4HaBzxH_mJn3AMPFWwEXvkDEPBVpaGANkmwKUDdK27hpHWZFZ0QUSkftmtnhTqzNbyKIYuB4zMqyY5XX9aC9fv1RkOnWHZza.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:03 2013-08-12 10:47:11 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/_zGVT5UxrXQveqA78HL1Cqaz6YJ6EaBE4HaBzxH_mJn3AMPFWwEXvkDEPBVpaGANkmwKUDdK27hpHWZFZ0QUSkftmtnhTqzNbyKIYuB4zMqyY5XX9aC9fv1RkOnWHZza.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/xewjxbVBpFJb5bwhF3zwFxy3RSSA4EvPrfxrSZ535HBzmeLQxjSCJpSA35hfil6FFcoyN5pCpvFfDhZ83bAH6q71q4BbzA1v2agdApfUAUZ-pySDacPfF6Si32J7WDpG.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/OV5nUY7AIMYZgorYVj1NKDPzNB7RQM8QjSJ09I9G_aIf5eFRlApRknn6bs1X1FNNMh38U3dInZseYfrQ_PXogo-BvlGtDvM2rm5cuTQ6vpDAijTPBvS9c303DHESIi-7.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632517 50000967225     9   9   50045650613 10000000378 43060   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/ZVxyJ-0PuuuUYQEKGBR-h0xFqKXENBzgjT5iPnI1rZWjxcyABQe-ASV8_eEfwWNWL8afBQTSmNKaJrUQvJw_CPyifGIzyKkcEF9G2oDlRCY3oYslNZbCFi3taPMDvGHs.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:04 2013-08-12 10:47:19 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/ZVxyJ-0PuuuUYQEKGBR-h0xFqKXENBzgjT5iPnI1rZWjxcyABQe-ASV8_eEfwWNWL8afBQTSmNKaJrUQvJw_CPyifGIzyKkcEF9G2oDlRCY3oYslNZbCFi3taPMDvGHs.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/FEY2ayWcs--SiZuKgGrEQCN962cWjfJoDfWUhNkruq3rhYQqk5sNEZeAv9V407s-Q1iyi-04P0tmRECL7PaPow_A5ZVkyCXEYwvupj_HVnr7ktDMgBrLeNEVRYIQw6J3.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/iv_M9T9x57RRNELPFNUwu8eozsqp8neqfVJanxZbrIX-j4_kfNy3u2knZSqKicjuPnsB-z-SpXwQyVYPlQ3F1cMlpBzSJ3oouhxNCUcQqr2p4DmfI48-cUL6F9xPdJ4Q.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632519 50000967225     1   1   50045650613 10000000378 53148   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/cKJeWNHdGjlNzGMfCPX4L_dc7iPRO78ADT-vbuzPlNgvOfnNse86npELRMuIhDLWxJ2sMytewzd40D4bPDNf4HSvOkYLSI6VYZZ76eM1rnqtlnLsutkWbzJpk6aTyI1b.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:04 2013-08-12 10:47:19 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/cKJeWNHdGjlNzGMfCPX4L_dc7iPRO78ADT-vbuzPlNgvOfnNse86npELRMuIhDLWxJ2sMytewzd40D4bPDNf4HSvOkYLSI6VYZZ76eM1rnqtlnLsutkWbzJpk6aTyI1b.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/InH6bCQ8o6nmQDKOtG7aD6ExqeRo2V_QdtIaGdEszW6dDKu2zY2MvPdn0jxWEy5BiSypaS24NHmL9TPlL8ZyiWICRGesaQB5iA_D-B5WmeIyibf8Oa-sK37X2dwuavin.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/KLDBeri17OuWfBFZF7NAN9jHLcGRn88kT0yyKF5e0O9aHme00f2NBTqtIuKSUAAgNWA9XCMJjlB7LxCdws_kO2Sw_KFlJMQcJt9siyWxbH6447ISKliXOi9BZ6h1TWbP.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632520 50000967225     14  14  50045650613 10000000378 41738   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/gFj5MVrUhLkOGBfNVy_vvj8KiqiVk3PqIdXpENQKxIYDuSpVkmYcrOIWjyFCfpdStV0Jb5-T24Qvnen0bho9bq1GQaLFwCfjJOZgNJwav-7bfOwbJ6gtV-6C9Qp3byub.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:04 2013-08-12 10:47:19 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/gFj5MVrUhLkOGBfNVy_vvj8KiqiVk3PqIdXpENQKxIYDuSpVkmYcrOIWjyFCfpdStV0Jb5-T24Qvnen0bho9bq1GQaLFwCfjJOZgNJwav-7bfOwbJ6gtV-6C9Qp3byub.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/nHqc1FIkgo2ZEKKUZr56-rAF2uhWNCYpbJfh5KC6vWmHP-z-a0Wddm9xNE4KZKPzB4mEwEOC3wLrmaPChNSl7wQ1rux1VceUX8vMgjSzF9NEpk0oB3Dmjd3sqzG7_z-i.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/6nhg64EnLMhmnarcoj_RQQgpsnsi__QG1hguLrVZATEIKmBpjLQutyImhaGkXl59ufVznuXBEBrpwlYshcu93EkexLWHPqWBPnbNGctnc1UKhNr94pjWvobcbs-fdfJk.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632521 50000967225     15  15  50045650613 10000000378 46788   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/Is4dbfVVzAj7pjkVIFbHJULHD9_B8xEl8oFKDcJwVBrXIbmpT2AUybGGN3nrkQeua6AjzGsQiZVvHGB7r-py3K-L5gMHVgdwhbaUEie1gMMIZPLFRDHzuw2yHzAIHVCJ.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:04 2013-08-12 10:47:20 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/Is4dbfVVzAj7pjkVIFbHJULHD9_B8xEl8oFKDcJwVBrXIbmpT2AUybGGN3nrkQeua6AjzGsQiZVvHGB7r-py3K-L5gMHVgdwhbaUEie1gMMIZPLFRDHzuw2yHzAIHVCJ.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/wPkmWXoXVrpSo0G22emzUcbN7olnaLysYFnwL11Hr_NpFpNZm7KcyDIpHhazr9Q3NuTTpzBnLZ95JVTTaxUWSDISNlIOQNbKYddbt-DwkEV01hud7bTGg7i-hiIhEbZj.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/ZtimYr6lmjGTjBetwU1XH5yqYnvewjt9zqI_6mEr_o6c3ehrMDheMq3CrVCPgYjTmm9YFqQUYa4QXf3fFzduxvOGtu8nxA_MMPXB4G8aq5bJhqIRFumuEqAwXSSJRR0m.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632524 50000967225     2   2   50045650613 10000000378 35582   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/2a7PoiDFANUZ1TVBGR6EI-BmX0nTU7GyX-U_KlxIrqsXE-_1SU0fku0yUhjhAR9_NadLiI8IYzCktv5yK2gBlvJwuazMCBWAm7FBexTOGhHgeQDjQNYjMIxUZo8JniNR.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:05 2013-08-12 10:47:21 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/2a7PoiDFANUZ1TVBGR6EI-BmX0nTU7GyX-U_KlxIrqsXE-_1SU0fku0yUhjhAR9_NadLiI8IYzCktv5yK2gBlvJwuazMCBWAm7FBexTOGhHgeQDjQNYjMIxUZo8JniNR.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/FtB4tjMYNw1FLh1krKwBarjpvnml4A1EPNACV6wI7Adrgu4yR0oisw-3Kq-vJBFLtgOmNHo_fEsE1FgeYwNDPayJlN2MeIM7-ucqhFdsXyfNjUsSIcjn4LT5vIoZD09X.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/Ignj31e_GBY0jsDq5wU7YADCudT-3OhpQ40DvYIXl8yWyipBZIVh1cUM6cBwnTEvHzh85h2dxRBjQwvGIOXVx4Mc22IlVfPjAH_oJkSNwx2ZbBjezFjnsOQZXBEScH5a.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632525 50000967225     3   3   50045650613 10000000378 38361   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/_aRTRAu4xJ3oA0eygZ7HUWxgK-40PCxtfpLgMXVWQ1g6ZhgKUThn4R6kTi2IWRa7uAfxd48pAGqhgH9DqGA9JrYXBg0YTEhMviy2pHzqpuckqPqC5YP_9tBC_aEfxmeS.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:05 2013-08-12 10:47:21 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/_aRTRAu4xJ3oA0eygZ7HUWxgK-40PCxtfpLgMXVWQ1g6ZhgKUThn4R6kTi2IWRa7uAfxd48pAGqhgH9DqGA9JrYXBg0YTEhMviy2pHzqpuckqPqC5YP_9tBC_aEfxmeS.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/ekRXDrSTaDldCJ19l7EDra18zZDZuLjhLawWsTdVkgzMwlWKWr8rEJiZHD_Mzwv50JZF_JYur5BTvsX6YFRJS6gy3o1uYQ1jd3fj1Qmv4Z90hVrwr7alZFGqI1vK2T1k.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/OsFlRx8KMwAXPpsuhJQXURpNqmG-oj7wvL6bb_kALQ_7-ZpcLjhz0HB6retpDnfSYNh-wg9PPrllTPYQOGPWw7OjZaAtsP5POYu14TririCIAy_cq7FOx1_nERMDdKyU.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632526 50000967225     4   4   50045650613 10000000378 49057   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/i9JIsOExag1-YYaBeXOvG72KRHG36FDiqoblJLlZEiSM2Fxgdoqe2d2Hhtd7u0FU6t3iuG2ZQ4B5E_UA7Kn3tyduumup6hpUaxZs9qgCf6HFOPDIeSQyD_C7Z5Q4SDBi.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:05 2013-08-12 10:47:22 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/i9JIsOExag1-YYaBeXOvG72KRHG36FDiqoblJLlZEiSM2Fxgdoqe2d2Hhtd7u0FU6t3iuG2ZQ4B5E_UA7Kn3tyduumup6hpUaxZs9qgCf6HFOPDIeSQyD_C7Z5Q4SDBi.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/2ljbPMvXApUMYXB6cWVI9FUj_vgGcb5cgtUrW7uMEQzSd5x_1_5N5-r0mXQRxBwjb2-HVTcQRw8h3VqmS5oIornjBSJ3fHdsnlBJJe2m4bEMKnd-a_wvTlonKLs_VU4B.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/j2JspCzA9f9_0aYPySromSx3zUPtKME11J-0TB-D9w3K_gG3oeX4hDwYXjMTCcZQ7iM-HO4p8zOMN0Y1DeKi0-C0htry5I8qcJinGG0p_hnDP-jYrSlKq6iWckJIC7HZ.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632528 50000967225     5   5   50045650613 10000000378 21161   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/REN7E37XSws4phInbScHwKJS0nKgHtSjrcqKhu_2Q56NfrDkuqyhYfd4yFvWy_ctaUNIZRScA3tJ22EumEcyMmXyehT9OrTCkU2wa84zb_knS6QPiGxZjxzScqX42I8g.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:05 2013-08-12 10:47:22 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/REN7E37XSws4phInbScHwKJS0nKgHtSjrcqKhu_2Q56NfrDkuqyhYfd4yFvWy_ctaUNIZRScA3tJ22EumEcyMmXyehT9OrTCkU2wa84zb_knS6QPiGxZjxzScqX42I8g.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/_dmEWWjhtufDlesrevYtsWdrsXv9JPuGlNauNIXdT_gx0OTeYLbN-QLBsQ3ht_gSNQNPmDTFrzafnl6iO5lwf1ESpCPCffKsZrzuPM_TuMC-COvhY-8uOFC6vgioVPEJ.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/e29qFLpKcbIfr_Cs_F-ldWRv1Ivn2IKOnJ8ynQQCO9x9lp5uKlMt9zXjNNliuVuUSGtbhGdLFRh94Ytkx4e_srwrUorZFNCZBPXrA4vJVXAGSdI-Hhb3qc6v8hdeqKwq.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632536 50000967225     6   6   50045650613 10000000378 56851   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/AE75xkGMz7GcgPA-DHxYtLiSiBpgFKPBngB_M6YEURz8v_MfzsyzAKjtKnARYJzO47QvjT3JwQL1t9SfJJbwobY7Sy05D8u7N4O8hGet6GLj2Ey7W_Wr9G8_PR5kHQ8K.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:06 2013-08-12 10:47:17 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/AE75xkGMz7GcgPA-DHxYtLiSiBpgFKPBngB_M6YEURz8v_MfzsyzAKjtKnARYJzO47QvjT3JwQL1t9SfJJbwobY7Sy05D8u7N4O8hGet6GLj2Ey7W_Wr9G8_PR5kHQ8K.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/JjpfgMXUqgjn2Dlj9JQu580fMoZqSlktrm2Y8SeFC0Q6HYt3K5BiDA8iqx_IPCXUB_3YxYopCr5oK5IxghO5BOcFbwfOYAxrfWCeft1zgG3ZaCwK6PL_ujKh7SkKIj2P.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/EN62d09TxNOzx6mvvKjfisN5jh--Gmz7LMhMJTvixRTcTtPOgZS9pcOU_0mD8NZB5kzPtXtoqRTqHQYe76DaHPzS8LDP9d_xE_hI2-wPToLjZ3ID9xXiUwDplLVR_Naw.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632549 50000967225     7   7   50045650613 10000000378 38316   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/XFFf_CQ91TwAtvGOG3WCeTtBAkm2tPBgU7uq9CUz_L2N1CwCcvw0ISTrT7n6-SvBDLrvRdTcHtJdBhc6b7IjJw25vi9p43K0YlTDP8RM6gUmWTfqQ0frSE5uRCgEaYnL.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:06 2013-08-12 10:47:18 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/XFFf_CQ91TwAtvGOG3WCeTtBAkm2tPBgU7uq9CUz_L2N1CwCcvw0ISTrT7n6-SvBDLrvRdTcHtJdBhc6b7IjJw25vi9p43K0YlTDP8RM6gUmWTfqQ0frSE5uRCgEaYnL.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/SPZLVtcwCeHFbX_MmGVEJMJDhhXYs1mDa4flUXvvq_iCPr58Ut6s2LvIF59RTMKvsx2GoYZVlkhF2hlEPiH9Npqb_CFucV8JCaZjPP3pWK1LdOfDILpXhTs2dzuCOWEZ.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/84iCvGTKtnimvu48xej-XvlavLLnwxIqQUD-4sIDQGZJQqFavRu48eXIqZZK1wPfdW_zWGfFLRqMh35IeC7hU5WqXBIRiw-eFb91x2gy_eSFx34b_UY0P24MWovG1ylk.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632560 50000967225     8   8   50045650613 10000000378 45512   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/sCMl2TEpLdCw7Trvq0lKez42G6uR85aYURcF5bqTv9u5YLYTo2me6ZXZ1D7JwaVKqHBvbJSzkYy6lE1oj1qNrxxoD3WxVOZCljjdoat-EtRBtp968NsB_r7jD6HqPw-p.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:06 2013-08-12 10:47:18 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/sCMl2TEpLdCw7Trvq0lKez42G6uR85aYURcF5bqTv9u5YLYTo2me6ZXZ1D7JwaVKqHBvbJSzkYy6lE1oj1qNrxxoD3WxVOZCljjdoat-EtRBtp968NsB_r7jD6HqPw-p.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/Zx7oXrKxSfvMGddUpb8sNKX_VQEv-A1dlarJnhq8yNVUwC_ZI0_2VAV4BXVFpytM4pMITjff4GzOFvKEKeLcnWvuXiMmBCgQUvOC7A0izvRxBWuc38q9MhEOPFecIIoc.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/C4o7bM_E9ouwZihyq_Vvh__f4EOJwRIWkQ89Wj7SJfX8aPGm0xAX2mQy2FAM7Fj2Am3e-Z7KqQnQQQ5FxY_rOlvhEJYbquNfg2oQxPWLQb-Eve10N8xL6C4yvUSxViu5.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632571 50000967225     16  16  50045650613 10000000378 33417   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/qsH3xTnoPsDyc2HdjQfXBJyOcDsXSsskv52b-KcKhmX5uch6w5s8kySvYtuGT0CTWdltLMTflwPWvjV5D_UNgwRkBH_DYgIw9YyqI5NjExsJHAHQ-2OgXA5zeMSs0pT_.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:07 2013-08-12 10:47:20 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/qsH3xTnoPsDyc2HdjQfXBJyOcDsXSsskv52b-KcKhmX5uch6w5s8kySvYtuGT0CTWdltLMTflwPWvjV5D_UNgwRkBH_DYgIw9YyqI5NjExsJHAHQ-2OgXA5zeMSs0pT_.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/eGW2t-dCg48broFOZEySaY7pZR8Y4xlrRhBZKAn3ZaZYAAd49P1BZX8MjZH-sp0q0oBXMMcp4RL7kEulXfJlp5kvMxL1bLK1tSTFH9vkmeRuJISpdJT3_cDfUNCF32Ou.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/yE-RsiXot_QuDG8JXNPz94jfKsa6X60O6yHbWPT9OfJlvyi9hCuZ0ccBwh9AHx7YP61zPBqLbfnGEldHpzxi-0xVkOn9HrnpEAQpBa-59tcPnbFXJ0rGkbFn94_Ckg8A.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632577 50000967225     17  17  50045650613 10000000378 27502   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/8URNbyPmlldaT_qtsiVZB3e7Mi_ZlMI_rTfaBXIarwhtINYHfuUtqBZGhAR2juQG5zIfOFfipe-dV0gbqRgXklCskB08a5yA3lkcnm-NAy7tSPEjAFmCCmTH5PxoZiuo.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:07 2013-08-12 10:47:20 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/8URNbyPmlldaT_qtsiVZB3e7Mi_ZlMI_rTfaBXIarwhtINYHfuUtqBZGhAR2juQG5zIfOFfipe-dV0gbqRgXklCskB08a5yA3lkcnm-NAy7tSPEjAFmCCmTH5PxoZiuo.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/IG3x9GB84ub9Ayiw0wCIe96dLG6T7syhjpSoS62hbPlYUa0v3XLN9VKzS_5ShemtvjL0_xSwo46Vn3nesgDO3ZbDdzPb03gE0B1gQSdpL99zM0FJk6p1AIP8zRLyDFzf.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/iIfd9HRfolnHMuCP9qTA_f2CJ_IE4270pS7BE3qGDgxj60csbIRoO2LHrWI6ABsDtszuZVzcdmoOtlEVm0cPG66nZmFsWsrEiyYXQB0E3BlTFd_qvUf3Lw71vSDfBxcE.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632581 50000967225     18  18  50045650613 10000000378 36192   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/pCdrMlbSUV-cpOq8ypreQQRHFJYvbWeOYh8kk1wAIb1nUCCROzmK-ajgSmz2TYpDRBienV32L2tI-tDcFBuJ_WeyIkzL3Pia4JRxHd8NOOGF1TMxa4QUt5AgSItqdwyY.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:07 2013-08-12 10:47:21 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/pCdrMlbSUV-cpOq8ypreQQRHFJYvbWeOYh8kk1wAIb1nUCCROzmK-ajgSmz2TYpDRBienV32L2tI-tDcFBuJ_WeyIkzL3Pia4JRxHd8NOOGF1TMxa4QUt5AgSItqdwyY.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/YhXAviVJSV-J4ixvV1c69tTrAoNS1LxoiP2c5VwP6ZjJBcrZdqT7DWd8xU15zTYp1b_lHj5s19O1H0wbBtmRebS70dpESUx4PWAf4yl21NXxkr5bYphK66s-tJqVWgIT.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/AVJxwzrAHiZA2wPdyAfrADK_7EeyEJ704Gk3M-7tRqdBf4w8R9cpFhzSHCeynvoJJ-dn7dEfvo8yOL2cgodafgI5TF0vfIbh_tsCM1EvCINg56tdCaB8B_kWTBtTwitP.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632582 50000967225     19  19  50045650613 10000000378 40515   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/HD2sE1Z4B5cl0iOPpPrBD7U23QwQhgVPV93AxB0XtVaTALvTzIqUeZqsniO-CfGGztz3axe5iuG4-9fzWzTFqUZwDIVaZHs2NwdaGAzdXxCnIfH2D_OG9RiWRhv2f5dT.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:07 2013-08-12 10:47:22 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/HD2sE1Z4B5cl0iOPpPrBD7U23QwQhgVPV93AxB0XtVaTALvTzIqUeZqsniO-CfGGztz3axe5iuG4-9fzWzTFqUZwDIVaZHs2NwdaGAzdXxCnIfH2D_OG9RiWRhv2f5dT.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/i3WkbqAMrDX2ciZsHf8jGfzztgcTeI47TIfggrmUh51n-eLUKdmVKsVrYamyprlWXfi-HXLh6e93riGyILDIj_PwtlgridFABgmPKB_XK9Sg5QyHi3DXBdo6qH4uLmFm.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/UyzZ2LTN9Sr83YaLNl7w9aU9geJQYHoa5HrzDbVWHPoC1ltR3u0naaE5xP801KEWTg2oHkjPEYMcNz9n0S4cxYlOEOx8YjRAIHFgAmg6io4Wf4fi7Ol2iXy_srUElxMB.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632642 50000967225     20  20  50045650613 10000000378 31265   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/oTBlzMCJbfGyveLcxzJCySfBysfihry1NCdM0UDFXK5m-bBbwjj3AWqts0dYNwZIamTSM3Ffhm2Ot7PortvWT_pcp6ykwN4PioYdKUMWsTYK2lDNHjW5lYn-bmjmXvDG.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:08 2013-08-12 10:47:23 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/oTBlzMCJbfGyveLcxzJCySfBysfihry1NCdM0UDFXK5m-bBbwjj3AWqts0dYNwZIamTSM3Ffhm2Ot7PortvWT_pcp6ykwN4PioYdKUMWsTYK2lDNHjW5lYn-bmjmXvDG.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/uAV2soj6rpdWvrMv_rfxUlt-GHrmRBDk3TYad6qi4vw9R_eDT4zCUoU0wtZhw5_Twz6OkFkK5SB_Mc85yjvCWgkdmqpoDjxEMHjTOnx5EFv6RiU_63i4C0FJRN-A2H1i.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/5XcJ5QDRZtB45o14RikM516OLbzKm-DW-RCUOoJk3442vOIIGStbQGGePUR9BmWdm7hSYO0-Vx9cF_qFDCWZzgSnIpVx_FqQrISHaif09hu1S0dux08Obpwy07FO4ouU.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632643 50000967225     21  21  50045650613 10000000378 33523   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/W2ZI2MzvRdL7WnXjBn_lAhy7wMFWdhSprH9UfnQSBbDSUnF4D2190qMic8reFlnbz194Qg-6YQoCqT-hN3Im89msxsV1IC4xacg7ZSpN-z2NZ7FqVwqrH3RCi7wPLzWc.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:08 2013-08-12 10:47:23 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/W2ZI2MzvRdL7WnXjBn_lAhy7wMFWdhSprH9UfnQSBbDSUnF4D2190qMic8reFlnbz194Qg-6YQoCqT-hN3Im89msxsV1IC4xacg7ZSpN-z2NZ7FqVwqrH3RCi7wPLzWc.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/uBicYRjHGtIjORvZr6_rJzTQV4bn9fE7m-ry1vhD3U0fN7tUWfOirpmdD84ESM3sJyNPeGabwCt0bnItypGi8J0FLMqNH50JiKoqYFtLs5LXWI40421IpKuOR2Qkv_WA.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/VyA7KoFiZgnZl-kCP6FKcQy-2j0denad7CDLmgZV9pADFYasZU_3eWdQ2FirAEnd-F9bDQONmOHv64L2T-7_uo7Me_IP74jBAniNXpBwh8qvRX22-vXa6MpkKsHS6NRI.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632646 50000967225     22  22  50045650613 10000000378 30072   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/Pb1vrkvbkXTHwBbw7B_lye_Ia6_xgQfhXyxn-LN5sUzIMIysgaIbRMlo-MXdHDFR6DxsqSPkespotPe8lERPok8CXeRmfCZI1vkcZWUv-8r6QyD_cJkiutzAIAWWzr3o.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:08 2013-08-12 10:47:24 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/Pb1vrkvbkXTHwBbw7B_lye_Ia6_xgQfhXyxn-LN5sUzIMIysgaIbRMlo-MXdHDFR6DxsqSPkespotPe8lERPok8CXeRmfCZI1vkcZWUv-8r6QyD_cJkiutzAIAWWzr3o.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/fTLaS-Sf0Q-LoQm8YvQDIZBOc0VWdivirDaQtl__k_FA_0GbKrMcOprAfx-xPbaqupbhZ8IlLaqpBYQx3aczlO7b8ye4pQpiwZ5_Yo0_t2Ewt9cgjQmipddb8xCP3nPe.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/7uHCpQYgPNlNfm2wxt6F_0ht0vyRsttsNfaz9-nCQ28tTmB4t-STtXa_sFbtkU8QewBJ3Mi5rGcAnxTsKu1MInLIB-zE9rIhXiJEiAYAAIOG8uvzxhtlw9SftDhP3Ogu.jpg  </DATA>
<DATA>  98317611445 98317632647 50000967225     23  23  50045650613 10000000378 21289   DB          http://example.com/image/V2/1/En4mBaA6V4sstC3w_aHWbcOPZPaVVKA_CWnfL2CpBdvZ-PpWBcLDtTW0xJS-fCIDCN__eZNvMX0RI_3M99u6kYqIkU5kO8DCRwic_oRr9puxL4U4f7GUs5uY_w9aQneU.jpg  2013-07-26 18:36:08 2013-08-12 10:47:24 10000003252 50040377470 50040377473 69664818:MRMLS  PW13148515  10000001073 480 640 http://example.com/image/V2/1/En4mBaA6V4sstC3w_aHWbcOPZPaVVKA_CWnfL2CpBdvZ-PpWBcLDtTW0xJS-fCIDCN__eZNvMX0RI_3M99u6kYqIkU5kO8DCRwic_oRr9puxL4U4f7GUs5uY_w9aQneU.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/YrzLKkOc9NF2wpeZGJ95b-FnrDPzVL2-E8Mfa_fzrDg9nqg69L7lBBMJvZGjadJ8F8RALjkvN4930ZnQYx5bvuqBrM7XfFahavabXZw69JtKBPK69EIScL9L5Ie9_3tF.jpg  http://example.com/image/V2/1/BWjfCubVSa3mbcvJpRJ6GCNptYjwo2aLIMCNV7hX3YtNDYZceUy9920gSN95iqBPCwoXjzlnACoMGMCgAC2NYbIf1Z7s3mV_X03cvocSajkvyOC9VLCGZkBQ6KLJH43c.jpg  </DATA>
</RETS>";

            var pattern = new Regex(@"/(http|https):\/\/(www\.)?[\w-_\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\/((([\w-_\/]+)\/)?[\w-_\.]+\.(png|gif|jpg))/g", RegexOptions.Multiline);
            var results = pattern.Matches(input);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Why does this not work, yet if I use http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and paste in the text it works perfect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove surrounding `/`. (C# does not use `/` as regular expression literal delimiter)

Some escapes are not required (`\/`, `\.` inside `[]`).

Remove trailing `g`.

```
var pattern = new Regex(@"(http|https)://(www\.)?[\w-_.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+/((([\w-_/]+)/)?[\w-_.]+\.(png|gif|jpg))");
```

**UPDATE**

You don't need `RegexOptions.Multiline` option.

Comment: @StephenPatten, I updated the code. forgot to remove trailing `g`.

Comment: 140 images extracted!

Comment: You should drop the `Multiline` option, too.  I know it's not hurting anything and that you just copied it from the question, but by doing so you're endorsing the OP's mistaken assumption that it's doing something useful.

Answer (score 2):

Like SQL, Regex is not a standard language. I assume that given that the website you have included is writen in flex, it uses Adobe's Regex, and .net using its own dialect.

Comment: That's true as far as it goes, but what exactly is wrong, and how can it be fixed?  This "answer" doesn't really answer anything.